# in Visual Basic 6.0: creating dynamic control array

Tags: vb6

I would like to duplicate a control on my form,
with a user control, which has the same name with a 'new' added to it.
(Label1 ----> newLabel1)

this is my code snippet:

```
Private Sub CreateLabel(ByRef lblControl As Control)

    'lblControl - this is the control i would like to duplicate


    'The reference to the new created control itself so i can work with it within this sub.
    Dim newControl As Control


    Set newControl = Form1.Controls.Add _
    ("Project.Project1", "new" & lblControl.Name, lblControl.Container)

    newControl.Visible = True

End Sub
```

It works great if i want to duplicate a control which isn't indexed
how ever, i am having trouble duplicating a control which is in an array as lblControl.Name simply take its name, not its index, and replacing the name with an indexed name (lblControl.Name & "(" lblControl.Index & ")" doesn't work really ..

In addition, creating a control and changing its index value after creation is not working.

So my question is, how can i create an array using the above method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a control is already a control array, then you use `Load` to create a new instance of the control.

Assuming you have a label `lblControl` with an `Index` set to 0 at design time (making it a control array), you would use the following code to add another instance of it.

```
Dim newControl As Control
Load lblLabelInControlArray(1) '1 is the Index value that will be sued
Set newControl = lblLabelInControlArray(1)
```

Obviously you will want to keep track on the Indexes you use, as VB6 does allow gaps so as you Load and Unload them it can get confusing.